# Find word with RegExp and bold

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I've a word document where I want to find all the words as have the following layout: ABC-12:123456 DEF. Where this is found in the document the word should be selected and put in bold. (Later i'll add a hyperlink instead of bold). I have successfully found the word and put it in a MatchCollection just to try RegExp. It looks like:

```
Sub searchDocument()
    Set matchPattern = New RegExp
    matchPattern.Pattern = "ABC-\d{2}:\d{6} DEF"
    matchPattern.Global = True

    Dim matchPatternWords As MatchCollection
    Set matchPatternWords = matchPattern.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)

    For Each matchPatternWord In matchPatternWords
        MsgBox (matchPatternWord)
    Next matchPatternWord
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go from the regexp match to the range object representing the match.

```
matchRange = ActiveDocument.Range
  (matchPatternWord.FirstIndex, matchPatternWord.FirstIndex+matchPatternWord.Length)
```

would be the obvious invocation.

However [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f73ca32d-0af9-47cf-81fe-ce93b13ebc4d/regex-selecting-a-match-within-the-document?forum=worddev) indicates that there might be issues with this approach, because formating can mess up the character count.  It's from 2010 though so the issue might be resolved in a better way now.

If the above doesn't work, or if you don't trust it you can do;

```
matchRange = ActiveDocument.Range.Find(FindText:=matchPatternWord.Value)
```

The latter needs a bit more handeling if multiple occurences of the same word is a possibility.

Once you have the range it's straight forward.

```
matchRange.Bold = True
```